# How can I use multiple Struts 2 configuration files?

Tags: java, struts2

It is possible to create multiple struts configuration files for the same module?

I have tried to create configuration file for different application/module and include it in main file `struts.xml` in Struts 2 but can anyone tell me how to create multiple configuration file for same application?

Comment: What do you mean by "different application"? Why would you want to include a different application's configuration? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are talking about struts.xml file so you can not create such multiple file.

The core configuration file for the framework is the default (struts.xml) file 
and should reside on the classpath of the webapp (generally /WEB-INF/classes).

though we have the option of  breaking up a large struts.xml file into smaller pieces.
You can use `<include>` elements in your `struts.xml` interchangeably,for example you can create configuration file for each module and can includes them in your struts.xml file like

```
<struts>
    <include file="Home.xml"/>
    <include file="Hello.xml"/>
    <include file="Simple.xml"/>
    <include file="/util/POJO.xml"/>
    <include file="/com/initech/admin/admin-struts.xml"/>
</struts>
```

Each included file must be in the same format as `struts.xml`, including the `DOCTYPE`. The include files can be placed anywhere on the classpath and should be referred to by that path by the "file" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible to have different struts configuration files.

you can create a main struts.xml file and then include other configuration files in this like

```
<include file="secondFile.xml" />

<include file="thirdFile.xml" />
```

All files will be having same syntax for configuration like DOCTYPE etc.

Comment: that I know but I am asking it is possible for different applications?

Comment: well, i think you asked **"pls tell me how to create multiple configuration file for same application?"**